# How to get correct layout of SwiftUI List Section with header and footer run on iOS 15, but built with iOS 14 SDK?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list, ios15

I have been testing my app (built using Xcode 12.5.1, i.e. iOS 14 SDK) on iOS 15 devices, and layout of SwiftUI Section headers and footers is wrong: there is too much bottom padding and not enough top padding on the header, and not enough top padding on the footer.

When compiled against the iOS 15 SDK (using Xcode 13 beta 5) it appears fine. However, I would like to have my app appear correct for any iOS 15 beta users; I cannot submit an updated built with the iOS 15 SDK until the GM release, so I would like to be able to "fix" this using just the iOS 14 APIs. Is there a good solution, or should I just manually fiddle with paddings?

Example SwiftUI view:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Header"), footer: Text("Footer text goes here.")) {
                    Text("Cell one")
                    Text("Cell two")
                }
            }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Hello Stack Overflow")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the following UI:

[image: Screenshot of app produced with above code]

The same code built on Xcode 13 and run on the same iOS 15 simulator produces the correct layout:

[image: The same code, built instead of Xcode 13]

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen this bug myself, but you can add padding to your header content if needed. Xcode 13 has a wonderful `Section(content:header:)` constructor that lets you provide a closure has the header, but since the goal here is to build with Xcode 12.5, let’s split the header out into a separate variable like so:

```
struct ContentView2: View {
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var header: some View {
        if #available(iOS 15, *) {
            Text("Header")
                .padding(.top, 16) // pad header to workaround bug
        } else {
            Text("Header")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: header, footer: Text("Footer text goes here.")) {
                    Text("Cell one")
                    Text("Cell two")
                }
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Hello Stack Overflow")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}
```

You can do the same for the footer.

Comment: Thanks - I'd not seen that new constructor. Yeah this is similar to what I've been playing with as a workaround. I also put in a `#if swift(>=5.5)` check in which I just return the non-padded version, so it will "just work" when I switch to Xcode 13 when the GM is out. I've padded my footers 6 on top, 16 on bottom; my headers 20 on top, 6 on bottom  - a bit of a guess. Feels a bit ugly 

Comment: Hopefully it’s just a bug. If you can reproduce the problem in a sample project, it’s worth filing a Feedback.